# For sets $A_1, \ldots, A_k$, with $n^2$ different elements, $|A_i| \geq 2n$, and every set pair $A_i, A_j$ shares at most 1 element, show $k \leq n$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, proof-verification

Given positive integers $n, k$, and:

$$ \left| \bigcup_{i = 1}^{k} A_i \right| = n^2$$

$$ \left| A_i \right| \geq 2n, \quad 1 \leq i \leq k$$

$$ \left| A_i \cap A_j \right| \leq 1, \quad 1 \leq i < j \leq k$$

We must show that $k \leq n$ in such a scenario.

I am going to attempt to prove this in two different ways:

1) What is the minimum number of *unshared* elements that every set must contain? To figure this out, we must minimize the total number of elements in every set (i.e. take every set to have $2n$ elements), and maximize the number of shared elements (i.e. every set must have one element shared for each remaining $k - 1$ sets). Thus, the minimum number of *unshared* elements must be:

$$ 2n - (k - 1) $$

Meanwhile, the average number of elements per set must be $n^2/k$, but this average must be greater than (or equal to, if $k = 1$), the minimum number of unshared elements in a set:

\begin{align*}
&\quad \frac{n^2}{k} \geq 2n - k + 1 \\
&\Rightarrow \frac{n^2}{k} \geq 2kn - k^2 + 1 \\
&\Rightarrow n^2 \geq 2kn - k^2 + k
\end{align*}

Assume that $k = n + 1$, in other words, that $k > n$. Then:

\begin{align*}
&\quad n^2 \geq 2n(n + 1) - (n + 1)^2 + n + 1 \\
&\Rightarrow n^2 \geq 2n^2 + 2n - n^2 - 2n - 1 + n + 1 \\
&\Rightarrow n^2 \geq (2n^2 - n^2) + (2n - 2n + n) + (1 - 1) \\
&\Rightarrow n^2 \geq n^2 + n \\
&\Rightarrow 0 \geq n 
\end{align*}

But this condition is trivially false since $n$ is positive, so we have reached a contradiction, thus $k \leq n$.

2) Take the case where no elements are shared between any pair of sets, and every set has the minimum number of elements, $2n$. Then the total number of elements if there are $k$ sets will be exactly $2kn$, so we have:

\begin{align*}
&\quad n^2 \geq 2kn \\
&\Rightarrow n \geq 2k \\
&\Rightarrow n > k
\end{align*}

It this condition did not hold, we would not be able to construct the above scenario, which is clearly valid. Thus, we must have that $k < n$ (note the strict inequality!)

---

Note that proof 2 does not show that $k \leq n$, but instead shows strict inequality. Is proof 2 correct in showing a stronger inequality than proof 1, or am I doing something wrong in proof 2?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I fixed this!

Comment: @bof Right, I updated the body/title with the points you brought up.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to edit the conditions again, please check if that is what you actually meant.

Comment: @MartinR Hi Martin, yup, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Work in progress ...**

Using [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and 
$$\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k}A_i\right|\leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\left|A_i\right| \tag{1}$$

**Case 1**
$$\left|A_i\bigcup A_j\right|=\left|A_i\right|+\left|A_j\right|-\left|A_i\bigcap A_j\right|\geq 2n+2n-(2-1)$$

**Case 2**
$$\left|A_i\bigcup A_j\bigcup A_t\right|=\left|A_i\bigcup A_j\right|+\left|A_t\right|-\left|\left(A_i \bigcup A_j\right)\bigcap A_t\right|=\\
\left|A_i\bigcup A_j\right|+\left|A_t\right|-\left|\left(A_i \bigcap A_t\right) \bigcup \left(A_j \bigcap A_t\right)\right| \overset{(1)}{\geq}\\
\left|A_i\bigcup A_j\right|+\left|A_t\right|-\left|A_i \bigcap A_t\right| - \left|A_j \bigcap A_t\right|\geq\\
2n+2n-(2-1)+2n-(3-1)$$

**By induction** 
$$\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k}A_i\right|=\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}A_i\right|+\left|A_k\right|-\left|\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}A_i\right)\bigcap A_k\right|=\\
\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}A_i\right|+\left|A_k\right|-\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(A_i \bigcap A_k\right)\right| \overset{(1)}{\geq}
\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}A_i\right|+\left|A_k\right|-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}\left|A_i \bigcap A_k\right|\geq \\
\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}A_i\right|+2n-(k-1) \geq 
\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k-2}A_i\right|+2n-(k-1-1)+2n-(k-1)\geq \\
... \geq 2kn - (1+2+...+k-1)=2kn-\frac{(k-1)k}{2}$$

**Altogether**
$$n^2 \geq 2kn-\frac{(k-1)k}{2} \Rightarrow k^2-(4n+1)k+2n^2 \geq 0$$

$$k\geq\frac{(4n+1)+\sqrt{(4n+1)^2-8n^2}}{2}=
\frac{(4n+1)+\sqrt{8n^2+8n+1}}{2}>3n \tag{2}$$
$$0<k\leq\frac{(4n+1)-\sqrt{8n^2+8n+1}}{2}<n \tag{3}$$

Now see if you can rule out case $(2)$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we build up the sets one at a time. So A_1 brings 2n elements, A_2 can being 2n-1, etc.  We see that the total size is (2n) + (2n-1) + ... + (2n - k + 1). Set this to = n^2 and solve for k

This is 2kn - k(k-1)/2 = n^2.  k^2 - 4(n+1)k + 2n^2 = 0. K < 2(n+1) - sqrt(2)(n+1) < 0.6(n+1)

As an example, take n=5. {1-10}, {1, 11-19} {2, 11, 20-28}. We're already over our limit. The equation there is k^2 - 21k + 50 = 0, first solution is when you run out of k, which is a little less than 3.

Edit: noticed this was proof review:

Your first proof is interesting, although second step could do with maybe a slicker argument. For example with k=n, you would also  see that n >= n+1 which is a contradiction too. Second proof doesn't work because you aren't packing the sets as tightly as you can? Imagine if we were to allowed intersect in all but 1 element for example. Then we could have something like k = (n - 1)^2